# Python prime function problems

Tags: python, function

I am very new to python; I only started two days ago. After looking at some designs online, i tried to use this function to determine if a number is prime:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("1 is not a prime.")
    if n == 2:
        print("2 is a prime number.")
    for x in range(2, int(n)):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n, "is a composite number.")
            break
        else:
            print(n, "is a prime number.")
            break
isprime(int(input("Enter a number.")))
```

The `isprime(int(input("Enter a number.")))` is so I can run the file as an .py.
However, while it runs without any errors, it returns false positives. For example, it states that 45 is a prime number. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Your `else` is incorrectly indented (and has an erroneous `break`), so the function returns too early.

Comment: Have a look at what you're actually doing. The only number you end up testing for a remainder is `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're aborting iteration of your `for x in range` loop after the first iteration, because both branches of your `if`-statement contain a `break`.

Remove the `else`-branch and use a [`for...else`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) construct:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("1 is not a prime.")
    if n == 2:
        print("2 is a prime number.")
    for x in range(2, int(n)):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n, "is a composite number.")
            break
    else:
        print(n, "is a prime number.")
```

Comment: Instead of `range(2, n)` you could use `range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1)`; you have already tested `n == 2` and there is no need to try higher than `floor(sqrt(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the logic of your code. Indentation plays an important role in Python. The code works good if it is changed like this:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("1 is not a prime.")
    if n == 2:
        print("2 is a prime number.")
    prime = True
    for x in range(2, int(n)):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n, "is a composite number.")
            prime = False
            break 
    if prime:
        print(n, "is a prime number.")
```